# ModelState Validation Error when get value from User.Identity.GetUserId()

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, identity, modelstate

in my WebApi controller post function I assign user id to my posted object through `User.identity.GetUserId()` but `ModelState.isValid` always return validation error that

> user id is required

while the value is assigned to the required property. So I removed the required attribute from `userId` property. It is working but I need to know as to why `ModelState` does not know that the user id has already been provided with `User.Identity.GetUserId()`.

Comment: maybe `User` is null?

Comment: No. it is not null as it is saving in the database. the problem is that I can't use [Required] attribute on this property. But removing this attribute does not make it sure whether the userId was passed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Web API 2, instead of `User.identity.GetUserId()` use

```
RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId()
```

or

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;

Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
```